# Unable to execute .htaccess in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache2

I have installed wordpress and it's working fine,  but requirement is to redirect http request to https using .htaccess but .htaccess file was not there, so i have created the file, but it's not redirecting. 
 Any help. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please check in the config for this site / host that override is enabled. If not change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` in the related config.
If this override is not enabled the .htaccess file will be ignored.

Like in the sample below...

```
        <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/my-host/httpdocs/">
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
```